# WCF Endpoint Configuration Issue

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm getting the following error when my ASP.NET 4.0 site loads, and it's because of my WCF service settings in the `web.config` file (I'm just not enough of a WCF expert and Google isn't helping :)):

> The endpoint at '[Path to my Service.svc]' does not have a Binding
>   with the None MessageVersion. 
>   'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior' is only
>   intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

I was using `webHttpBinding` but was getting the following error, so now I'm using `basicHttpBinding` after [following the advice of this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/03/23/preventing-anonymous-access.aspx):

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication
>   but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this
>   service.

Anyways, here's the relevant info from my web.config.  Please help!

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ABC.ProjectName.Web.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ABC.ProjectNameDell.Web.ServiceBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
                             aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBinding_AnonymousDisabled" >
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="ABC.ProjectName.Web.AjaxService" >
      <endpoint address="/" 
                behaviorConfiguration="ABC.ProjectName.Web.ServiceBehavior"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="ABC.ProjectName.Web.AjaxService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use basicHttpBinding with enableWebScript. Set your binding to WebHttpBinding.

```
  <service name="ABC.ProjectName.Web.AjaxService" >
    <endpoint address="/" behaviorConfiguration="ABC.ProjectName.Web.ServiceBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="ABC.ProjectName.Web.AjaxService" />
  </service>
```